# React routing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

I'm building a react SPA with Wordpress running as the backend, but it's **not headless**, so the entire frontend is included in the theme. I simply run npm build and enqueue the production files in the functions.php file. The application is rendered into a `<div id="root"></div>` inside a template file. My wordpress install is set to have a static homepage, which uses the template that contains the React root div.

This seems to work just fine, apart from the Router. If I go to a different address, say `https://mywebsite/about`, it tries to load a wordpress page named `about`, rather than staying on the same page, and using the router to render the appropriate component. Is there something setting I have to change in the .htaccess file? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Do normal links in your SPA work fine? Is it just direct access to URL's that result in 404?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. The links work fine (it changes the URL and renders the correct component). It only breaks when I enter a URL manually.

Comment: It is still headless if you are using react only for the theme, and pulling data from WP Api. Headless doesn't imply that you cannot use it as a WP theme.

Comment: As far as I know, a headless website is one in which backend and frontend are completely independent. In this case, the frontend is embedded within backend, it is not stand alone. Some of the displayed data is pulled from the REST API, but some is rendered by php on first page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the answer lies inside the .htaccess file.

You need to set up a catchall rule, which will serve *index.php* file for all routes instead of trying to find a matching php file for the route which is happening now.

You should be able to use this config to achieve such behaviour:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Solution does imply you are using modrewrite on your server.

Comment: This worked indeed, but I found out that in addition I needed to turn off permalinks (via dashboard -> settings -> permalinks -> set to 'plain'). Prior to this, when all traffic was being routed to index.php, the wordpress router was catching this traffic before the react router.

Comment: Strange, I'm using custom Post Name or  Custom Structure permalinks with this config without issues

Comment: With this approach I am getting a 404 error in console (altought react handle the routes well). Is there a way to make wordpress response a 200 instead of 404?

Answer (score 16):

If you have a React app on your WP page and you don't want to edit .htaccess you can also add rewrite rules with *add_rewrite_rule()* in functions.php to redirect all requests to your react app WP page to be handled by React Router.

```
add_action('init', 'wp55290310_rewrite_rules');

function wp55290310_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^your-react-app-root/(.+)?', 'index.php?pagename=your-react-page-name', 'top');
}
```

You need to specify the baseName in React Router:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/your-react-app-root">
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={SomeComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/other-page" component={OtherComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: also, it's needed a flush of WordPress permalinks. Just enter to Setting >> Permalinks and save changes. It will flush your "permalinks cache".

Comment: The `add_rewrite_rule` works, thanks. I didn't need to set a `basename`, just works with React Router `5.1.2`

Comment: What should i include for 'your-react-page-name'

Comment: @CraZyDroiD 'your-react-page-name' should be the slug of the page you are redirecing to (eg, yoursite.com/testpage/ -> testpage).