# I want to use react route function, but can't I classify it by parameter?

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wp-admin

I can not speak English very well
Thank you for your understanding

The cause is a problem that occurred while trying to use react in the WordPress admin menu.

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Switch>
     <Route path="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jouranl" component={list} exact />
     <Route path="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jouranl&id=1" component={detail} exact />
```

Is there any way to use it?

To apply to wordpress based on php, you need to use query paramter.
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=journal/ <- list
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=journal&id=1 <- detail

Looks like there's no way

I will ask if I can ask for advice

Comment: Try [React routing in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55290310/2873538)